# Linking CalendarView To Device Calendar

Tags: android, calendar

Is there a way to link the CalendarView widget to the built in Calendar on a mobile device? For example, when I click on any date in my CalendarView, it brings up the device's google calendar so I could set reminders and so forth.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_date);

    calendarView = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendar);


    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

         //Could I place the code in here?
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Convert your year/month/day into date-time specified in milliseconds since the epoch.
long startMillis = ...
Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
builder.appendPath("time");
ContentUris.appendId(builder, startMillis);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setData(builder.build());
startActivity(intent);
```

[Using intents to view calendar data | Calendar Provider | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-view)